# Is there a more elegant way of adding an item to a Dictionary<> safely?

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

I need to add key/object pairs to a dictionary, but I of course need to first check if the key already exists otherwise I get a "**key already exists in dictionary**" error. The code below solves this but is clunky.

**What is a more elegant way of doing this without making a string helper method like this?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestDictStringObject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> currentViews = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            StringHelpers.SafeDictionaryAdd(currentViews, "Customers", "view1");
            StringHelpers.SafeDictionaryAdd(currentViews, "Customers", "view2");
            StringHelpers.SafeDictionaryAdd(currentViews, "Employees", "view1");
            StringHelpers.SafeDictionaryAdd(currentViews, "Reports", "view1");

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in currentViews)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class StringHelpers
    {
        public static void SafeDictionaryAdd(Dictionary<string, object> dict, string key, object view)
        {
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                dict.Add(key, view);
            }
            else
            {
                dict[key] = view;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 312, accepted):

Just use the indexer - it will overwrite if it's already there, but it doesn't *have* to be there first:

```
Dictionary<string, object> currentViews = new Dictionary<string, object>();
currentViews["Customers"] = "view1";
currentViews["Customers"] = "view2";
currentViews["Employees"] = "view1";
currentViews["Reports"] = "view1";
```

Basically use `Add` if the existence of the key indicates a bug (so you want it to throw) and the indexer otherwise. (It's a bit like the difference between casting and using `as` for reference conversions.)

If you're using C# 3 *and you have a distinct set of keys*, you can make this even neater:

```
var currentViews = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "Customers", "view2" },
    { "Employees", "view1" },
    { "Reports", "view1" },
};
```

That won't work in your case though, as collection initializers always use `Add` which will throw on the second `Customers` entry.

Comment: Excellent, didn't realize simple assignment took care of the add/overwrite issue, nice.

Answer (score 64):

What's wrong with...

```
dict[key] = view;
```

It'll automatically add the key if it's non-existent.

Comment: One thing I think is worth noting that if you are storing an int, `dict[key] += amount` will not work if the key doesn't exist

Answer (score 28):

simply

```
dict[key] = view;
```

From the MSDN documentation of Dictionary.Item

> The value associated with the
>   specified key. If the specified key is
>   not found, a get operation throws a
>   KeyNotFoundException, and a **set
>   operation creates a new element with
>   the specified key**.

My emphasis

Answer (score 13):

Although using the indexer is clearly the right answer for your specific problem, another more general answer to the problem of adding additional functionality to an existing type would be to define an extension method.

Obviously this isn't a particularly useful example, but something to bear in mind for the next time you find a real need:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void SafeAdd<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, 
                                             TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        dict[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd mention this is only applicable to C# 3.0 and above.

Answer (score 11):

As usual John Skeet gets in there with lighting speed with the right answer, but interestingly you could also have written your SafeAdd as an Extension Method on IDictionary<K, T>.

```
public static void SafeAdd(this IDictionary<K, T>. dict, K key, T value)...
```

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov this answer builds on [John Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1177534/11178549) answer, so the reference should be preserved IMHO.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias An answer on SO should be a self-contained one, not be 'built on' some other answer. If you believe rohancragg just offers to take JohnSkeets's code and just put it into another form (extension method), then this answer actually holds no value on top of the JohnSkeets's one and should be a comment instead.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov in retrospect this answer seems to suggest an alternative signature for the `SafeAdd` extension method posted in [Daniel Earwicker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1177590/11178549). Which is impossible because Daniel Earwicker posted their answer 3 minutes *later* compared to this answer. Sincerely I am not sure what's going on with this answer. Maybe the author (rohancragg) could clarify whether the reference to John Skeet's answer is significant and should be preserved.