# Updating Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've a problem with updating a dictionary

I also have read many topics about this saying all the same (e.g. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177517/is-there-a-more-elegant-way-of-adding-an-item-to-a-dictionary-safely))

```
ExampleDict[key] = value;
```

I was trying this to my own code:

Model:

```
  public Dictionary<int, string> Info { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<int, string> GetInfo(int id)
    {
        Info = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        var game = db.Games.Find(id);

        var playerOne = db.Players.Find(game.PlayerOneId);
        var playerTwo = db.Players.Find(game.PlayerTwoId);
        var PlayerOneName = playerOne.Nickname;
        var PlayerTwoName = playerTwo.Nickname;
        int scoreOne = CountScorePlayerOne();
        int scoreTwo = CountScorePlayerTwo();


        // old aproach:
        Info.Add(scoreOne, PlayerOneName);
        Info.Add(scoreTwo, PlayerTwoName);

        //new approach
        Info[key] = scoreOne;

        return Info;


    }
```

Error

> The name 'key' does not exist in the current context

Note: I'm a student and this is for a school project.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

**Solved through the code sample from Jon Senchyna, Thank you!**

Comment: The `Key` is the first parameter for the `Add` method. It almost looks like you _want_ to have `Info[key] = PlayerOneName`. Or plausibly, your _old_ code was incorrect and you _should_ have had: `Info.Add(PlayerOneName, scoreOne)` EDIT: So I'm betting later on you're accessing the dictionary via the wrong key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that you are never declaring the variable `key`.  You probably did not mean to use "key" in the "new approach" line.

In addition, I believe your `Dictionary` is backwards, as it looks like the player name should be the key, not their score.  The way you are currently declaring it (`Dictionary<int, string>`), you are creating a dictionary whose keys are `int` (score?) and whose values are `string` (name?).

Here are my suggested edits:

```
// Corrected dictionary definitions
public Dictionary<string, int> Info { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, int> GetInfo(int id)
{
    // You may want to use a local variable here instead
    Info = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    ...

    Info[PlayerOneName] = scoreOne;
    Info[PlayerTwoName] = scoreTwo;

    return Info;
}
```

Here are some useful links for learning more about using the Dictionary class (and C# in general if you browse around a bit):

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)
- [DotNetPearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

In the example link in your question there's the method:

```
public static void SafeDictionaryAdd(Dictionary<string, object> dict, string key, object view)
```

Which has a `string key` as an argument. You need to define that key, too.