# Add Metadata to stripe on customers

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

It is such that I need to add a unique identifier to the customer. via stripe metadata. This is how I built it completely finished now but I have however just the last part as to tell me which package the user has purchased.

I've tried to look here:

[Plans to stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#plans)

Code here:

```
  var planType = abonnement.fk_userid != null ? "Business" : "Default";

  planService.Create(new StripePlanCreateOptions()
  {
     Amount = 99 * 100,
     Name = abonnement.mdr + " - (" + planType + ")",
     Currency = "EUR",
     Interval = "month",
     IntervalCount = 6,
     Id = 1,
     Metadata =
     {
         "Pakkeid:" = abonnement.PriceValueUnikId
     }
  }
  );
```

Error on **Metadata**

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or
>   indexer
>
> Invalid initializer member declarator

Its a **Dictionary**

[image]

Comment: what type is `Metadata`? is it a Dictionary or Object?

Comment: If I hover over the metadata that tells them it is: Dictionary

Comment: `Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string> { {"Pakkeid", abonnement.PriceValueUnikId } }`

Comment: @Rob thanks for comment! i hope u will give me a +1 for my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example showing how to use metadata with [Stripe.net](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net): https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net#updating-a-bank-account

You should modify your code like this:

```
planService.Create(new StripePlanCreateOptions()
{
    Amount = 99 * 100,
    Name = abonnement.mdr + " - (" + planType + ")",
    Currency = "EUR",
    Interval = "month",
    IntervalCount = 6,
    Id = 1,
    Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "Pakkeid", abonnement.PriceValueUnikId }
    }
}
);
```

Comment: Oh that I had not just seen. But super nice that you found it. I give you +1 point and hope you will give me the same for my question. Good day to day!

Comment: But after i see u Answer, i see its here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1177534/6115825