# Return Value on Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

It is such that I must return the key parts that add no value.

key states that I've written but I would like to have out of this one return is just VALUE.

I've looked at ContainsKey who are here on this page.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

the way I put "PakkeidUnik" into the metadata field you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605865/6115825

I therefore get hold of Value as you can see here:

```
return stripeCustomer.Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
     Dictionary["PakkeidUnik"];//HERE ARE ITS ERROR!
};
```

My **error** are here:

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: Its not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? Let us know what inputs you are using and what results you are expecting.

Comment: @Jamiec Thank you for telling it, that I must get hold of it PakkeidUnik Value as you can see in the picture that I have updater on the issue.

It is Pakkeid value that I must get hold of.

Comment: Dictionaries allow you to look for a value by key - sounds like you're looking for the key.

Comment: What's the question? If you meant to ask why you're getting the compile error; it's because you can't initialise a `Dictionary<string,string> with a string key only; but `Dictionary["PakkeidUnik"]` doesn't make any sense either as `Dictionary` is a type object not an instance object

Comment: Do you have the value and want to find the key, or do you have the key and want to find the value?

Comment: i will "do you have the key and want to find the value" @Jamiec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking, you but seem to say you want to get the value for that key (having already set the values per your other question).

You simply use the indexer and pass the key:

```
return stripeCustomer.Metadata["PakkeidUnik"]
```

How to use a dictionary is covered in [the article you've found](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary).  You also might find the examples in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) useful.

Comment: Thank you very much thank you for your help. it was just the solution which caused the problem to work.

Hope you will give me +1 for the issue. Good day and enjoy days.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing the dictionary initiator syntax, and the syntax for reading the value from a dictionary based on a known key.

A dictionary can be initialised with values like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>()
{
    {"Key1","Value1"},
    {"Key2","Value2"}
}
```

If you then want to read one of the values by key you use this:

```
var value = dict["Key1"]; // value will contain "Value1"
```

Answer (score 0):

See the code below:

```
stripeCustomer.Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
     { "PakkeidUnik", "The Value You would like to return for key PakkeidUnik" }
};

return stripeCustomer.Metadata;
```