# IDictionary Extension method for Adding if key not present

Tags: c#, extension-methods

[This old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1177570/4225229) suggests making an extension method for this purpose, but the answer is 9 years old, so C# is probably different since then, or I don't understand the implementation.

I am currently trying this:

```
public static void AddIfNotPresent(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, TValue value)
{
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        dict.Add(value);
    }
}
```

... but Visual Studio says "The type or namespace TKey cannot be found...", same for value... Why can't I add these arbitrary types to an extension method?

Comment: You have to add those type parameters as generic parameters to the method. And they will ne inferred. `public static void AddIfNotPresent<TKey, TValue>(this ....`

Comment: If the key already exists? You want to discard the  value passed to the method?

Comment: If you're targeting .net core 2.0+, there is a [TryAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.tryadd?view=netcore-2.1) method to `Dictionary`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TKey` and `TValue` should be type parameters of `AddIfNotPresent` and `AddIfNotPresent` should be defined in a static class.

```
void Main()
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dictionary.AddIfNotPresent("key", "value");
    Console.WriteLine($"{dictionary.First().Key} = {dictionary.First().Value}");

    // Output: key = value
}

public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void AddIfNotPresent<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dict.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `AddIfNotPresent` does not define those generic types/arguments (`AddIfNotPresent<TKey, TValue>`). That answer is missing those which is a typo.